# How to change site URL for Admob?

Tags: admob

I've created an android app and added admob ads to it. but while creating admob site i've given the URL as "http://...", and now I want to change it to "market://..."

I could not find how to edit the site URL. Does anybody know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on the `manage settings` button (on your desired app). Then at the top you should see an `edit` link next to the title. Click on this and you will see an editable `Android Package URL` field.